# How to get 401 response without handling it using try/catch in android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am using `HttpUrlConnection` to make network requests from my android application. Everything works fine except one thing, 401. Whenever the server returns response with status code 401, my app throws `IOException` with a message stating, `"no authentication challenge found"`. After googling it, I haven't found a single solution, but only workaround (handling it using try/catch, assuming its a 401 response).

here is the code snippet:

```
public Bundle request(String action, Bundle params, String cookie) throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, SocketTimeoutException,
        IOException {

    OutputStream os;

    String url = baseUrl + action;
    Log.d(TAG, url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(30 * 1000);
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", System.getProperties().getProperty("http.agent") + "AndroidNative");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    if (cookie != null) {
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
    }

    if (params != null) {
        os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(("--" + boundary + endLine).getBytes());
        os.write((encodePostBody(params, boundary)).getBytes());
        os.write((endLine + "--" + boundary + endLine).getBytes());
        uploadFile(params, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }

    conn.connect();

    Bundle response = new Bundle();
    try {
        response.putInt("response_code", conn.getResponseCode());
        Log.d(TAG, conn.getResponseCode() + "");
        response.putString("json_response", read(conn.getInputStream()));
        List<String> responseCookie = conn.getHeaderFields().get("set-cookie");
        // Log.d(TAG, responseCookie.get(responseCookie.size() - 1));
        response.putString("cookie", responseCookie.get(responseCookie.size() - 1));
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        throw new SocketTimeoutException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.putInt("response_code", HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.putString("json_response", read(conn.getErrorStream()));
    }

    // debug
    Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        List<String> values = map.get(key);
        for (String value : values) {
            Log.d(key, value);
        }
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    return response;
}
```

I really want to know, why this exception is thrown? What does authentication challenge mean? How to provide authentication challenge? what change I have to make in my code to overcome this situation?

Please enlighten me.. :)

Comment: I'd guess it means that the server responded with a 401 error code but omitted the `WWW-Authenticate` header which describes the authentication challenge.

Comment: server has got the `WWW-Authenticate` header, but still I am getting this error.

Comment: I just ran into this, and also cannot figure out how to get this response code back without having to just assume it's a 401 after catching the IOException (since `getResponseCode()` itself will throw the same IOException as `connect()/getInputStream()/getOutputStream()`). From the stacktrace it seems `org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1153)` is responsible for throwing the exception up the chain (although I couldn't dive any further).

Comment: Also, the server I'm connecting to expects a session cookie along with my http requests. It seems as long as I provide one (doesn't even have to be a vaid one) I can avoid the IOException. Also my IOException error message is slightly different "Received authentication challenge is null".

Comment: Hey Thanks! after setting invalid cookie, I am getting response code! But now, It's throwing `FileNotFoundException` and I am not getting response content (I am supposed to receive JSON response from server). Now, when I call `conn.getErrorStream()`, it throws `NullPointerException`. Can you help me with that? About the message, you get different message because your server is not sending `WWW-Authenticate` header with the response.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IOException is quite a general exception, and you cannot safely assume a 401 status code every time it's thrown.

If the first time you request the status code it happens to contain a 401, HttpURLConnection will throw an IOException. At this point, the internal status of the connection will have changed, and it will now be able to give you the status code, without any error.

```
int status = 0;
try {
    status = conn.getResponseCode();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // HttpUrlConnection will throw an IOException if any 4XX
    // response is sent. If we request the status again, this
    // time the internal status will be properly set, and we'll be
    // able to retrieve it.
    status = conn.getResponseCode();
}
if (status == 401) {
    // ...
}
```

For more details, http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, IOException is a very general exception. It can be thrown for anything. from your answer, I am assuming that I have to write another try/catch block inside the main try/catch block to be sure that the exception is thrown because of retrieving response code. In that case, this is again a workaround! But since, its been an year and I haven't found any solution, I am accepting your answer!

Comment: This fixed the issue with Android Version 4.2.2 and under

Answer (score -2):

try to use HttpClient

```
private void setCredentials(String login, String password) {
    if (login != null && password != null)
        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(URL_HOST, 80), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(login, password));

}



private InputStream execute(String url, String login, String password) {
        setCredentials(login, password);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                return stream;
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "Wrong response code " + code + " for request " + get.getRequestLine().toString());
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I really don't want to use `HttpClient` since its not that much light weight. In case of file uploading, I will have to use another third party library (`MultipartEntity`), which doesn't come with android SDK. I do need to keep the apk size small. Moreover, google suggests to use `HttpUrlConnection` because its lightweight and they are actively working on that.