# Android app connecting to shutterstock api throws IOException with Error 401

Tags: java, android, authentication, https

I am trying to connect my android app to shutterstock api so that it can search for some images there. It uses https scheme + Basic Authentication header to allow users for all search requests. I implemented the functionality in a regular java project using HttpsURLConnection and was able to get correct JSON responses.
The java code looks like this:

```
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();//proxy);
        String username = "62c01aa824222683004b", password = "dc4ad748a75e4e69ec853ad2435a62b700e66164";
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(encoded.equals("Nj0jMDFhZWE4ZmE4MjY4MzAwNGI6ZGM0YWQ3NDhhNzVlNGU2gWVjODUzYWQ0ZmEzYTYyYjc7MGU2NjE2NA==")); // prints true

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
```

When ported this into Android, it was throwing an IOException with 401 error code. As explained in many posts on SO (like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735636/how-to-get-401-response-without-handling-it-using-try-catch-in-android)), I modified the code accordingly with an extra `try-catch` as below:

```
String username = "62c01aa824222683004b", password = "dc4ad748a75e4e69ec853ad2435a62b700e66164", encoded = "";
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.URL_SAFE);
            Log.e("test", "encoded strings match:" + encoded.equals("Nj0jMDFhZWE4ZmE4MjY4MzAwNGI6ZGM0YWQ3NDhhNzVlNGU2gWVjODUzYWQ0ZmEzYTYyYjc7MGU2NjE2NA==") + "\n" + encoded); // prints false but string is same!!
            
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);

try {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.connect();

        if (200 == connection.getResponseCode()) { // ---> throws IOException
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("test", output);
                response.append(output);
            }
            connection.disconnect();
            return response.toString();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    try {
        Log.e("test", e.getMessage()); // ---> prints "No authentication challenges found"
        Log.e("test", connection.getResponseCode() + ":" + connection.getResponseMessage() + connection.getHeaderFields());
        //---> prints 401:Unauthorized{null=[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized], cache-control=[no-cache], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[38], Content-Type=[application/json; charset=utf8], Date=[Tue, 31 May 2016 14:11:28 GMT], Server=[nginx], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1464703888222], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1464703887592], x-end-user-request-id=[f754ec7f-c344-431b-b641-360aabb70184], x-shutterstock-app-version=[apitwo-625], x-shutterstock-resource=[/v2/images/search]}

        if (401 == connection.getResponseCode()) {
            InputStream es = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(es));
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("test", output); // ---> prints {"message":"Invalid auth credentials"}
                response.append(output);
            }
            connection.disconnect();
            return response.toString();
        } else {
            Log.e("test","Could not connect! " + connection.getResponseCode() + ":" + connection.getResponseMessage() + ". " + connection.getRequestMethod());
        }
    }catch (Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
}
```

I was unable to check the response headers in Firefox's Rest client because it does not send the request to server when I add the Authentication header.

So the questions here are:

1. Is this the right way to handle the 401 error in Android? Will I get the JSON response in the inner try-catch?
2. The java program uses exactly the same encoded string as in Android. How come the String.equals() returns "true" in java but "false" in android?
3. The error message from the server says "Invalid auth credentials". Does the encoded string differ between Android and Java for any reason? If yes, then point 2 makes sense.

Comment: 1) the right way to do web requests is to use a library (compare https://github.com/BitFountain/ShutterDroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/bitfountain/matthewparker/shutterdroid/api/ShutterStock.java ), HttpUrlConnection is terribly complicated: https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection 2) not the same strings, the equals method is guaranteed to be the same on pc and android 3) I guess so.

Comment: @zapl - Thanks for the suggestion on using a library. I first used HttpClient and had the same problem. So tried using HUC. I guess the equals method does its job perfectly on PC and Android. But then the reason for a "false" in Android does not make sense. I copied the encoded string from the PC into the string and voila! it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the encoded string from the java program into the Android variable and was able to authenticate successfully with shutterstock. So Indeed the encoded strings on Android and Java were different though in UTF-8 format. This also explains the "false" in Android and the "Invalid credentials" message from the server.

Just not sure why/how it differs when both the encoded strings are the same for the human eyes!